Alter Javascript hash inline
My script is like this, TableCell has the one element sx which works like a stylesheet
Material-UI
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-cell/
var sx = {padding:"10px 0px 10px 0px",fontSize:"0.75rem"}

<TableCell sx={sx}></TableCell>
<TableCell sx={sx}></TableCell>

then I want to change the color only for second TableCell
So, What I want to do is like this,
 <TableCell sx={sx}></TableCell>
 <TableCell sx={{sx.push(backgroundColor:"#AAAAAA")}}></TableCell>

or
 <TableCell sx={sx}></TableCell>
 <TableCell sx={sx} sx={{backgroundColor:"#AAAAAA"}}></TableCell>

However these cannot be work and two sx element is not permitted.
How can I make this?

You can use { ...sx, backgroundColor: "#AAAAAA" }.

@Shuo It works perfect!! thank you very much
